# Dominator Tree of a Rascal Graph

Tags: graph, functional-programming, rascal

Is there a way to calculate the dominator tree from the [Graph type](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Rascal.html#/Rascal/Libraries/analysis/graphs/Graph/Graph.html) using a more imperative approach? The language has a support to create such data structure directly?

I'm trying to extract a dominator tree from a Graph using the following algorithm ([here is the link for the original article](https://www.cs.au.dk/%7Egerth/advising/thesis/henrik-knakkegaard-christensen.pdf)):

[image: dominance tree algorithm]

But I'm having trouble in adapting those `for` and `while` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some choices to make, like for example how to represent the output dominator tree. One typical way is to choose Graph again. Later you could transform the Graph to a constructor tree if you like by another function.

Given that choice for Graph[&T], the following template could become a rather literal translation of the given algorithm into Rascal:

```
Graph[&T] dominators(Graph[&T] graph, &T root) {
  result = {};
  V = carrier(graph);
  Pred = graph<to,from>;

  solve(result) {
     for (v <- V, u <- Pred[v]) {
        if (...)
     }
  }
  return result;
}{
```

However it is unnecessary to go to the "pred" form of a graph by first inverting it and then continously looking up predecessors, we can directly loop over the edges as well, and this is much much faster:

```
Graph[&T] dominators(Graph[&T] graph, &T root) {
  result = {};
  
  solve(result) {
     for (<u, v> <- graph) { // u is the predecessor of v
        if (...) {
          result += { };
        }
     }
  }

  return result;
}
```

A basic fixed point solver directly from the definition in the Dragon book (and also equation 3.2 in the thesis you cited). (Note I just typed this in, haven't tested it so it may be buggy):

```
rel[&T, set[&T]] dominators(graph[&T] graph) {
  nodes = carrier(graph);
  result = {};
  preds = graph<to,from>;

  solve(result) {
    for (n <- nodes) {
      result[n] = {n} + intersect({result[p] | p <- preds[n]?{}});
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

(with intersect a library function from the `Set` module)

And here is a "relational calculus" solution, which solves the problem using the `reachX` library function and returns a relation from each node to the set of nodes it dominates (taken from Rascal documentation files):

```
rel[&T, set[&T]] dominators(rel[&T,&T] PRED, &T ROOT) {
  set[&T] VERTICES = carrier(PRED); 
  return { <V, (VERTICES - {V, ROOT}) - reachX({ROOT}, {V}, PRED)> | &T V : VERTICES};
}
```

Comment: Also see `demo::Dominators`

Comment: When trying to run `{result[p] | p <- preds[n]?{}}` I'm getting "Expressions of type set[void] cannot be subscripted". I don't know how to fix this, any idea?

Comment: @MateusLuiz that's maybe a bug in the type-checker. You can ignore it for now .

Comment: It worked, thanks! Also, instead `intersection` I used `union`, an undefined function error was being raised

Comment: @JurgenVinju is there also a build in idom finder for a given node and dominance tree? Something like the demo::Dominators

Comment: @MateusLuiz I think you can use relation projection like this `dominators[givenNode]` in most cases. Have to watch out which direction the relation is, maybe reverse graph first like this: `dominators<to,from>`